# If else statement not covered in Code Coverage in Jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine

When I use Jasmine marbles for unit testing for if condition those specific blocks don't cover in code coverage report.
Is there a way to unit test if blocks so that they would be covered in code coverage report?

```js
activeClass(menu: MenuList): void {
  this.menuList && this.menuList.map((element: MenuList) => {
    if (element.menu_name === menu.menu_name) {
      element.active = true;
      this.gotoSelectedRoute(element);
    } else {
      element.active = false;
    }
  });
}
```

```js
const menuList: MenuList[] = [{
  menu_name: 'MENU_LIST.NEW_BOOKING',
  class: '',
  url: 'services',
  is_hosted: true,
  is_shown_login: true,
  showOnCondition: 'isHostedWithLogin',
  is_hide_login: true,
  hidden: false,
  displayOrder: 1,
  options: null,
  active: false,
}, ];
describe('activeClass', (): void => {
  const menu: MenuList = menuList[0];
  const menuListdata: MenuList[] = menuList;
  it('should call activeClass', fakeAsync(() => {
    selectMenuDataMock.setResult(menuList);
    store.refreshState();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.activeClass(menuList[0]);
    expect(component.activeClass).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  it('should both the menu name needs to be same', fakeAsync(() => {
    selectMenuDataMock.setResult(menuList);
    store.refreshState();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.activeClass(menu);
    menuList.forEach((element) => {
      element.menu_name = 'MENU_LIST.NEW_BOOKING';
      menu.menu_name = 'MENU_LIST.NEW_BOOKING';
      expect(element.menu_name).toEqual(menu.menu_name);
    });
  }));

  it('should active be true', fakeAsync(() => {
    selectMenuDataMock.setResult(menuList);
    store.refreshState();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.activeClass(menu);
    menu.active = true;
    menuList.forEach((element) => {
      expect(element.active).toBe(true);
    });
  }));

  it('should gotoselected', fakeAsync(() => {
    selectMenuDataMock.setResult(menuList);
    store.refreshState();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.activeClass(menu);
    const spy = spyOn(component, 'gotoSelectedRoute').and.callThrough();
    menuList.forEach((element) => {
      element.active = true;
      component.gotoSelectedRoute(element);
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(element);
    });
  }));

  it('should active be false', fakeAsync(() => {
    selectMenuDataMock.setResult(menuList);
    store.refreshState();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.activeClass(menu);
    menu.active = false;
    menuList.forEach((element) => {
      expect(element.active).toBe(false);
    });
  }));

});
```

Not sure whether the coding style for unit testing is correct or not let me know if needed any improvement.

from above ts file from if block code is not covered not sure where i am going

this is case i am trying to write it Thanks.

[image]

Comment: `this.menuList` looks like it probably isn't getting initialized so that code is not getting called.   Presumably `selectMenuDataMock.setResult(menuList); store.refreshState();  fixture.detectChanges();` is supposed to set this up.  If you put a breakpoint in `activeClass` does `this.menuList` look like you expect?

Comment: @possum yes it is like i expect

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not getting coverage on the if statement is because your component.menuList is null.  Since the menuList is null the code doesn't bother running your map function.

To rectify, simply give your component.menuList a valid value prior to calling the activeClass function.

Comment: prior to calling activeclass i am creating dummy json called menuList as you can see the code

Comment: That's not what I was referring to.  

activeClass(menu: MenuList): void {
  this.menuList && this.menuList.map((element: MenuList) => {

You're validating this.menuList and not menu (the parameter being passed in).

Your choices are:

1. Change your code to use menu parameter. or 2. Change your test to set the value of your component.menuList.